# Media Queries funciona em smartphones mas não em resolução para tablet

Tags: css3

Estou criando uma página com layout responsivo, em relação a resoluçao de *smartphones* funciona normalmente, quando aumento para tablet não dá nenhum resultado. Porquê?

```
@media(max-width:480px){
    div#formulario{
        width: 250px; 
        height:300px;
    }   
}

@media (min-width:481px)and(max-width:960px){
    div#formulario{
        width: 350px; 
        height:400px;
    }
}

@media(min-width:961px){
    div#formulario{
        width:450px; 
        height:500px;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi Lamborghini. Dá uma melhorada na formatação do código, por favor. É só [edit] a pergunta, selecionar o código e clicar no botão `{}` do editor. Mais detalhes em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help. **Bom, o @brasofilo deixou meu comentário obsoleto antes mesmo de eu publicá-lo; mas fica a dica.**

Comment: Na primeira regra não deveria ser `min-width`?

Comment: Desculpe por demorar pra responder @bfavaretto min-width funcionou tudo esta ok

Comment: Será? Percebi agora que a minha sugestão não faz muito sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo com seu código e também alguns ajustes no `CSS` (especificação dos tamanhos mínimos e máximos).

```
#formulario {
    background:#000;
}

@media (max-width: 480px ) {
    #formulario {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 960px) {
    #formulario {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #formulario {
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
    }    
}
```

[Exemplo JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rk80qv9y/1/)

Apenas para complemento vamos esclarecer a regra:

Estamos em uma tela de `800x600px` (Largura x Altura) ao acessar o site a regra aplicada será:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 960px)
```

Pois numa resolução mínima de `480px` até um máximo de `960px` aplica-se as regras.

Caso a resolução seja superior a `960px` a regra que será aplicada será:

```
@media (min-width: 960px)
```

Comment: muito bom @Diego Vieira li um tópico a respeito disso e resolvi tudo mesmo assim valeu